# SQL last insert in Drupal. Is it really threadsafe?

Tags: mysql, drupal, concurrency, multithreading

I have a query that might be executed by several users consecutively. I'm scared that if I run the db_last_insert_id command, some users might not get the last insert id, due to concurrency. But according to: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_last_insert_id/6, it sates:

> Returns the last insert id. This function is thread safe.

My question is, how is this thread safe? The code is only:

```
<?php
  function db_last_insert_id($table, $field) {
   return db_result(db_query("SELECT CURRVAL('{". db_escape_table($table) ."}_". db_escape_table($field) ."_seq')"));
  }
?>
```

I don't see anything about locking tables or nothing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using MySQL *(as you seem to indicate with the tags on your question)*, the function [`db_last_insert_id()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_last_insert_id/6) is defined this way :

```
function db_last_insert_id($table, $field) {
  return db_result(db_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'));
}
```

in `database.mysql-common.inc`

And [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) depends on the connection *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> The ID that was generated is
>   maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that
>   the value returned by the function to
>   a given client is the first
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for
>   most recent statement affecting an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client.
>   This value cannot be affected by other
>   clients, even if they generate
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own.
>   This behavior ensures that **each client
>   can retrieve its own ID without
>   concern for the activity of other
>   clients**, and without the need for
>   locks or transactions.

So, I'd say that this is quite OK for MySQL ;-)

The definition your posted is actually the one used for PostGreSQL :

```
function db_last_insert_id($table, $field) {
  return db_result(db_query("SELECT CURRVAL('{". db_escape_table($table) ."}_". db_escape_table($field) ."_seq')"));
}
```

In `database.pgsql.inc`

From [pgsql manual on sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/functions-sequence.html) *(quoting ; emphasis mine)* :

> `currval`
>
> Return the value most recently
>   obtained by nextval for this sequence
>   **in the current session**. (An error is
>   reported if nextval has never been
>   called for this sequence in this
>   session.) Notice that because this is
>   returning a session-local value, **it
>   gives a predictable answer whether or
>   not other sessions have executed
>   nextval since the current session did**.

So, I'm guessing this is quite OK too, for PostGreSQL.

Comment: Thank you. I wish i could give you ten UPS.

Comment: You're welcome :-) huhu ^^ you'll have to ask 10 other questions, to which I know the answer :-D